# What will be the smallest value of $k$ such that $P(k)=m$?

Tags: partitions, ordered-groups, isomorphism-testing, ramanujan

Let us suppose that we have a group of order $p^k$, where $p$ is prime.In General,there is one group group of order $p^k$ for each set of positive integers whose sum is $k$(such a set is called partition of $k$) i.e, if $k$ can be written as $k=n_1+n_2+...+n_i$,where each $n_i$ is a positive integer then $\mathbb Z_{p_{n_1}}\oplus \mathbb Z_{p_{n_2}}\oplus\mathbb Z_{p_{n_3}}\oplus...\oplus\mathbb Z_{p_{n_i}}$ is an abelian group of order $p^k$.Uniqueness of fundamental theorem guarantees that distinct partition of $k$ yields isomorphism classes.

So,Number of distinct isomorphism classes of group of order $p^k$ are partition of $k$ i.e.,$P(k)$.Now,suppose we want $m$(or approximately $m$) isomorphic classes ,then **What will be the smallest value of $k$ such that $P(k)=m$?**

Are any research paper available related to above problem?

Although I try to solve this via Ramanujan Partition function,but i'm unable to represent $k$ explicitly in terms of $m$.
it'll be very helpful if someone provide some suggestions related to above problem

Comment: we have $\log P(k)\sim c\sqrt{k}$, thus $k\sim c^{-2}\log^2 m$, where $c=\pi\sqrt{2/3}$

Comment: Do you want to consider all groups of order $p^k$ or only abelian groups? If you want all groups, then the number of isomorphism classes is larger than the number of partitions of $k$. For example, there are $14$ isomorphism classes of groups of order $16 = 2^4$, of which only $5 = P(4)$ are abelian, see [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_16).

Comment: You might enjoy https://oeis.org/A000001 which tabulates the number of groups of order $n$. Also, https://oeis.org/A046057 is "Smallest order $m>0$ for which there are $n$ nonisomorphic finite groups of order $m$, or $0$ if no such order exists." If you really want only abelian groups, you can probably find the relevant entries for those at the OEIS, too.

Comment: Have any of these suggestions been helpful, P.S?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:yes,Michael Albanese helped upto some extent...Now,I'm finding some new tool as Partition function is erratic

Comment: As a footnote to @FedorPetrov's comment, I believe your sequence matches [OEIS A329202](https://oeis.org/A329202) up to $n=30$ and it has a similar definition.